# Can't get ion-tabs working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I tried to set up tabs like in [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNOpMb) but as you can see there no content is shown. I do:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button" ng-click="done()">
            Done
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-view>
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
        Content of One
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-clock" icon-off="ion-ios-clock-outline">
        Content of Two
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
        Content of Three
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

And if i select Home `Content of One` is not showing up. I just copied the code from the official side: [Ionic ion-tabs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/). Also my `ion-nav-buttons` are not showing up in the `ion-nav-bar`.

What is wrong with my code?

Is it possible to get the tabs to the top of the screen? i dont want the bottom i want them top. I also need to change the color and transparency if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bipin Bhandari suggested, you're a missing a few things in your code.
At some point you might want to use routing and a controller.

Having said that, you can simply render a page with TABs using this code:

```
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
            <ion-nav-view>
                <ion-content>
                    Content of One
                </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-clock" icon-off="ion-ios-clock-outline">
            <ion-nav-view>
                <ion-content>
                    Content of Two
                </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
            <ion-nav-view>
                <ion-content>
                    Content of Three
                </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>

</body>
```

With this you don't even need to define a controller or manage states and everything would work just fine.

This is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOaWez?editors=101).

Here, you're not using the standard navigation system as you're not using states and you don't have a default `<ion-nav-view>` where all the subviews would be injected; see ref. [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/).

If you want to add a button to your header you can only add it inside the `<ion-header-bar>`:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button">Done</button>
      </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Of course working with something like this wouldn't be feasible, considering you're building a working application and you need controllers, navigation and history.

The way to go is to define a `<ion-nav-view>` in your body:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>  

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

Defining states during the configuration of your application:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'homeController',
    });
```

and adding an html page with your view and tabs:

```
<ion-view view-title="home">

    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only tabs-striped tabs-top">

        <ion-tab title="Tab1" icon-on="ion-ios-home" icon-off="ion-ios-home-outline">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-1">
              <ion-content padding="true" has-header="true">
                  <h1>HOME</h1>
              </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Tab2" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-2">
              <ion-content padding="true" has-header="true">
                  <h1>SETTINGS</h1>
              </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Tab3" icon-on="ion-ios-information" icon-off="ion-ios-information-outline">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-3">
              <ion-content padding="true" has-header="true">
                  <h1>INFO</h1>
              </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>

</ion-view>
```

If you want to see how it works this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cuFY80WIV2XDHpZDn2u4?p=info) should do.

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for. i dont want any routing for my tabs. that is totally unlogical for in an app to have a backstack when i switch between tabs. thank you.

Comment: Kind of agree with you :-) Cheers.

Comment: @Mulgard: Updated my answer with some more info. Codepen is updated as well.

Comment: Hello my friend. I noticed a problem with that solution. When i now press the back-button when im in my tabs view it goes back 2 times not only once. do you have an idea why?

Comment: That's the reason why you might want to integrate states. States use history. You're not doing any of these things.

Comment: i dont understand why not having states leads to a double back trigger.

Comment: Updated my answer.To answer your question I should have a look at your application. How you configure it etc etc.

Comment: its a very very huge project. i tried it with the states but i always got redirected to my homepage and i couldnt figure out why.... and i also dont want a push to the backstack when i just switch a tab.

Answer (score 1):

In the codepen, there is no script for routing and tabs won't work without it. Docs of ion-tabs could be misleading because it only shows the html part.

You basically have two ways to get a functioning ion tabs. One is create fresh new ionic project with tabs:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

In this project you could see well implemented tabs and customise it to your need.

Or you could browse its source code to see how its implemented. Source code is here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs

Good luck!